# Editing tag wikis of not-so-popular tags

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Some tags have so few questions and answers that the combined score of all answers won't reach 100.

Shouldn't the score requirement depend on the popularity of the tag or total rep "distributed" in the tag (capped to 100 points)?

Comment: Isn't it relatively easy to be one of the top 20 answerers in that case?

Comment: See also: [Tag 'lsp' has no wiki info - and no-one will be able to provide it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63849/tag-lsp-has-no-wiki-info-and-no-one-will-be-able-to-provide-it)

Answer (score 6):

That's why we say ... Top 20 answerers OR 100 total score (bronze badge)